# How to get a list of IDataRecord from IDataReader returned by Snowflake .net client?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, idatareader, snowflake-task

If we use Microsoft SQL Database, then we get SQLDataReader object when ExecuteReader() function is executed. So we have a function for converting SQLDataReader object into **List of IDataRecord** which can be used later on when the connection is closed:

```
List<IDataRecord> rows;
using ( var result = command.ExecuteReader() )
{
    rows = result.Cast<IDataRecord>().ToList();
}
```

But I have to use snowflake client to get rows from snowflake warehouse. And ExecuteReader() function in return gives IDataReader object. But I am unable to get a list of that whole data maybe in any dataset that can be used later. Can anyone guide me that how I can get all the returned rows from snowflake warehouse into a list?

Comment: There is an example of using the .NET connector with Snowflake here.  Does it answer your question?  https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net

Comment: As far as reusable data, does the .NET connector provide you with the query_id of your execution?  If so, you could always use the result_scan() function of Snowflake to get the same result again from cache.  Just a thought.

Comment: @MikeWalton thanks for response. Well let me explain further, In this GitHub link if you go through this section  > Run a Query and Read Data < , Notice that after running ExecuteReader() you will get IDataReader type object. And for getting rows out from it we are doing reader.Read(). I do not want to use reader.Read() loop to get all the rows and then push them into a list one by one. I want to know is there any function that we can apply on reader object to get a list of all rows?, Like in SQL server, we can convert SQLDataReader object to List<IDataRecord> to use after connection is closed